# How to create generic method for comparing two objects

Tags: java, generics

Okay. Write a program that has a Class 2D class that contains methods for calculating volume and surface shape. Then
create classes Rectangle, Circle and Triangle that inherit the Class 2D class and implement its methods.For
Rectangle, Circle, and Triangle class to declare necessary attributes for calculating volume and surface. Then make a Class ShapeUtill. The class ShapeUtill should contain and implement static methods for
Comparison of two forms of volume and surface (total 2 methods). Methods should receive generic types like
parameters that must be classes inherited by Form 2D

Before my main problem, I tried to implements(overridng) method from one class to another and I did that in this way, is good or?

```
 @Override
 public void areaAndVolumeOfCircle(Circle c) {
 double areaCircle = Math.pow(c.getR(), 2) * Math.PI;
 double volumeCircle = 2 * c.getR() * Math.PI;
 }
```

So my main problem is, how to implements two generic methods to compare area and volume of two shapes(circle, rectangular or triangle).

In my class Shape2D i have this methods:

```
    public void areaAndVolumeOfCircle(Circle c) {
    double areaCircle = Math.pow(c.getR(), 2) * Math.PI;
    double volumeCircle = 2 * c.getR() * Math.PI;
    }

    public void areaAndVolumeOfRectangual(Rectangular r) {
    double areaRectangle = r.getA() * r.getB();
    double volumeRectangle = (2 * r.getA()) + (2 * r.getB());
    }

    public void pIObimTrougla(Triangle t) {
    double areaTriangle = t.getA() + t.getB() + t.getC();
    double volumeTriangle = (t.getB() * t.getH() / 2);
    }
```

Also, class `Circle, Rectangular, Triangle` extends class `Shape2D`.

So I want to implements two static generic method in new class `ShapeUtil` to compare two objects.

I tried that in this way, but doesnt work(type Circle does not take paramaters)

```
   public static <T, I> void compare(Cicle<T, I> c, Rectangular<T, I> r) {

   }
```

Thank you, Im here if I need to explain something better!

Comment: Why do all your methods return `void`?

Comment: Create an abstract `area()` method in Shape2D, and override it in every subclass. Remove all your areaAndVolumeOfXxx methods.  Then write a method `compareByArea(Shape2D shape1, Shape2D shape2)`

Comment: But I want to do this with generic method

Comment: What do you mean with compare? Just a boolean awnser of they are equal? Something more like is bigger?  What kind of response do you need?

Comment: @JohnWilliams That's like wanting to travel using a hammer. A hammer is useful for some tasks, like hitting on nails. But not for travelling. Generics are useless here. Given your code, you should first learn some important concepts, like inheritance, polymorphism, instance vs. static methods/

Comment: I want to compare to objects, for example two circles, or circle and triangle and to see who has a larger surface area and scope/volume

Comment: Your shape2D should be an interface with `area()` method so you can implement it in your Rectangle and Circle class. To answer your real problem if you implement `Comparable` interface and implement its `compareTo` method, your problem is solved

Comment: Then why you want a ShapeUtil class when this responsability belongs to your Shapde2D class?
Create a method like `isBiggerThan(Shape2D x)` in the class and then you can make abstract protected the rest of the functions that you need to compare it

Comment: Can you help me a little more with code, how I can implements methods in Rectangle and Circle class?

Comment: Have you at least tried to do it? Edit your question, and show what you tried.

Comment: I tried to do it, I already posted my code how I tried, with generic method, and you are going around my question

Comment: I told you how to do it: Create an abstract area() method in Shape2D, and override it in every subclass. So, have you tried doing it? I also told you that using generics to solve this problem didn't make sense. Have you read and understood this comment?

Comment: Flagged your comment, the guy knows much more Java than you do. And this is definitely not a problem which should be solved by generics

Comment: What are `T` and `I` type parameters in your `Circle` and `Rectangular` classes? Can you show us definition of those classes?

Comment: T and I ? I cant see that in my calss

Comment: In your question there is `Cicle<T, I>` and `Rectangular<T, I>`.

Comment: I tried to create generic method

Comment: I am getting the impression that you may not fully understand your assignment requirements, or have not fully explained them to us, as much of what you're posting doesn't fully add up. Consider clarifying things greatly.

Comment: Check again my question, I edited

Comment: So now you know that you will need to use a bounded generic type -- look this up and then try to implement. Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: I cant delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create an abstract class `Shape2D` which will be super class to all your figures(Circle, Rectangles etc.). You create a method `compareArea` and an abstract method `area`.

```
abstract class Shape2D {
    double area = 0;

    abstract double area();

    int compareArea(Shape2D that) {
        return Double.compare(this.area, that.area);
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape2D {
    private float radius;

    public Circle(float r) {
        this.radius = r;
        area = area();
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        area = 3.14 * this.radius * this.radius;
        return area;
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape2D {
    private float side1, side2;

    Rectangle(float side1, float side2) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        area = area();
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        area = side1 * side2;
        return area;
    }
}
```

I think you should read some java book to know how Java and OOP work, it will save you a lot of time not thinking about doing stuff which is not possible such as doing this with generics.

Comment: Can you tell me why I cant do this with generic? Is that because circle and triangle cant save String type?

Comment: Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: Can you just tell me Am right for that one?

Comment: No, your reason is not correct

Comment: So can you tell me why I cant use generic in this way?

Comment: I provided you a link to read, you will know your reason. I and many other have already said, this is not the use case for generics.

Comment: I already read that article and I still dont know other reason why I cant use generic in this whay? Can you tell me? You said I cant use generic in this way, can you explain me why?

Comment: Because generics allows a type or method to operate on objects of various types while providing compile-time type safety.

Comment: Okay, but If I put that my Circle object is String, how method can calculate area if I put numbers bettwen " " ?

Comment: why would you want to store your numbers as strings? Anyway, use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` or similar `Long`, `Double`, `Float` method.

Comment: @JohnWilliams: your comments about Circle type as a String, really don't make sense I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

First of all my solution is trying to reach a high cohesion with low coupling. I really can't understand why you have methods which don't return anything and calculate two different things (area and volume)

Have a class which compares two objects that belongs to the same hierarchy sounds weird and I'm not understanding why Circle has generics.

Having said that this design provides you a way to compare objects pushing the logic to class avoiding

```
abstract class Shape2D {
    abstract double area();
    boolean isBiggerThan(Shape2D shape) {
        return this.area() > shape.area();
        //or volume, or create a method hasBiggerAreaThan and hasBiggerVolumeThan
    }
}


class Rectangle extends Shape2D {
    /*Create constructor of rectangle*/

    @Override
    double area() {
        return this.height * this.width;
    }
}
```